# How to access plotly figures properties that are not explicitely set by the users

Tags: python, plotly

I want to access plotly figure attributes that are automatically set by the library (I do not personally specify their values).
For example, when constructing a simple histogram, the minimum, and maximum values for the axis are computed automatically, as illustrated by the code below (copy pasted from plotly documentation https://plot.ly/python/histograms/)

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(500)

data = [
go.Histogram(
    x=x
)
]
py.iplot(data)
```

image of simple histogram generated from plotly:
[image: image of simple histogram generated from plotly]

How can I access to the properties of the figure such as the axes ranges, the ticks, the ticks labels?

Answer (score 0):

I only know's plotly javascript library, but the reference is similar to the other libraries - e.g. R.
Here is a link to an explanation how you can modify your axes in R: https://plot.ly/r/axes/
I think this should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the parameters can be specified in the [`layout`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout) options, e.g. the following snippet will give you a histogram with a [x-axis range](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-range) from -2 to +2.

```
import plotly
import numpy as np
plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='', api_key='')

x = np.random.randn(500)

data = [
  plotly.graph_objs.Histogram(
    x=x,
  )
]
layout = dict(
    xaxis=dict(
        range=[-2,2]
    )
)

figure = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.plotly.plot(figure)
```

[image: Plotly plot]

Comment: Thank for your reply, I am indeed aware that you can specify the range through the xaxis option. However, I am looking something that can scrape the xrange of the figure withouth the need to specify the option. In matlab, it is relatively easy to get axes properties with something like: 'get(gca, 'xtick') where 'gca' refers to the current axis. Is there somthing similar with plotly?

Comment: @greghor Thanks for the clarification! I misunderstood your question, as far as I know you cannot do that directly in Python with Plotly. In Javascript you can the values indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

For certain properties, perhaps:

```py
fig = px.scatter(x=[10, 20], y=[20, 10], height=400, width=400)
fig.show()
xdomain = fig.layout.xaxis.domain
```

See [Plotly docs](https://plotly.com/python/figure-introspection/):

> ## Introspecting Plotly Express Figures
>
> Figure objects created by Plotly
> Express have a number of attributes automatically set, and these can
> be introspected using the Python print() function, or in JupyterLab,
> the special fig.show("json") renderer, which gives an interactive
> drilldown interface with search:
>
> ```py
> import plotly.express as px
>
> fig = px.scatter(x=[10, 20], y=[20, 10], height=400, width=400)
> fig.show()
> print(fig)
> ```

Output:

> ```
> Figure({
>     'data': [{'hovertemplate': 'x=%{x}<br>y=%{y}<extra></extra>',
>               'legendgroup': '',
>               'marker': {'color': '#636efa', 'symbol': 'circle'},
>               'mode': 'markers',
>               'name': '',
>               'orientation': 'v',
>               'showlegend': False,
>               'type': 'scatter',
>               'x': array([10, 20]),
>               'xaxis': 'x',
>               'y': array([20, 10]),
>               'yaxis': 'y'}],
>     'layout': {'height': 400,
>                'legend': {'tracegroupgap': 0},
>                'margin': {'t': 60},
>                'template': '...',
>                'width': 400,
>                'xaxis': {'anchor': 'y', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'title': {'text': 'x'}},
>                'yaxis': {'anchor': 'x', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'title': {'text': 'y'}}} })
> ```